# Facebook login integration in my PHP code gives error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I click on the Facebook login button I got this error.

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

```
This is my website url:-http://192.168.1.234/photogallery/login.php
```

in my app settings i have written this
Website with Facebook Login

```
Site URL: http://192.168.1.234/photogallery/login.php
```

Then what's the problem in site url?

Thanks in advance... :)

```
public function getLoginUrl($params=array()) {
    $this->establishCSRFTokenState();
    $currentUrl = $this->getCurrentUrl();

    // if 'scope' is passed as an array, convert to comma separated list
    $scopeParams = isset($params['scope']) ? $params['scope'] : null;
    if ($scopeParams && is_array($scopeParams)) {
      $params['scope'] = implode(',', $scopeParams);
    }

    return $this->getUrl(
      'www',
      'dialog/oauth',
      array_merge(array(
                    'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                    'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten
                    'state' => $this->state),
                  $params));
  }
protected function getCurrentUrl() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
        ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
        isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
      $protocol = 'https://';
    }
    else {
      $protocol = 'http://';
    }
    $currentUrl = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parts = parse_url($currentUrl);

    $query = '';
    if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
      // drop known fb params
      $params = explode('&', $parts['query']);
      $retained_params = array();
      foreach ($params as $param) {
        if ($this->shouldRetainParam($param)) {
          $retained_params[] = $param;
        }
      }

      if (!empty($retained_params)) {
        $query = '?'.implode($retained_params, '&');
      }
    }

    // use port if non default
    $port =
      isset($parts['port']) &&
      (($protocol === 'http://' && $parts['port'] !== 80) ||
       ($protocol === 'https://' && $parts['port'] !== 443))
      ? ':' . $parts['port'] : '';

    // rebuild
    return $protocol . $parts['host'] . $port . $parts['path'] . $query;
  }
```

Comment: That IP is a local IP on your network, you need your external IP.

Comment: then what to write in external ip? @benfortune

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean canvas url is `http://192.168.1.234/photogallery/login.php` ?If so then change it to `http://192.168.1.234/`

Comment: what is called canvas url? @vishnu vishwa ?

Comment: in your facebook app settings , there will be field to enter your website url , Please enter http://192.168.1.234/ there.

Comment: only this 192.168.1.234 ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code. When generating the `token_url`, can you ensure that the `redirect_uri` is set to `http://192.168.1.234/photogallery/login.php`?

Example:

```
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . $app_id 
            . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode('http://192.168.1.234/photogallery/login.php')
            . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret
            . '&code=' . $_SESSION['fb_'.$app_id.'_code'];
```

Comment: this is my $token_url 192.168.1.234/photogallery/login.php @stephane Bruckert

Comment: You integrated a Facebook login into your website. So, you most probably had generated a `token_url`. Didn't you?

Comment: in my code $currentUrl = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your *Basic* Settings in your *Apps Settings Page* is configured wrong.

You are using your local host as the site URL. Maybe facebook has no access to the location. **Please upload the files into a server like http://www.000webhost.com/.**

Make sure the following are entered correctly.
I am assuming you are using *Facebook Login for your website* and the app is not configured for *App on Facebook* or *Android* or *iOS*.
In the *Website with Facebook Login* option `SiteURL` you should enter your domain address of the website.

That should solve your problem.